# What is the best way to teach interdisciplinary engineering topic?

Tags: engineering, education, interdisciplinary

After hours or even days contemplating about how engineering fields could be distinguished each others, especially on interdisciplinary topics, I am questioning about what the best way that could be done to teach interdisciplinary engineering (e.g. in bachelor degree) for students?

I'm an academia in Indonesia and watching that the bachelor programs in interdisciplinary engineering topics are most likely gravitated into a single broad engineering topic, based on the curriculum (trying not to generalizing it). Take an example, Biomedical Engineering. There's so many universities that running the program that heavily lied on the Electronic Engineering topics, but as we know, Biomedical Engineering is more than electronics. It composed by the application of engineering in material, mechanical system, and biochemical reaction. Thus, I think the curriculum is not the best way to support knowledge transfer in interdisciplinary engineering.

Is it because of the education background of the lecturers that is not various enough? So, is it better that, take an example again, Biomedical Engineering, has faculties that have various education background so the department could teach many aspect on the topics?

How could we make the program special? e.g. Biomedical Engineering and Material Engineering on Biomaterial topic. Or is it not necessary to make the topic distinguished on two different department?

I would be very pleased if you could give me the example of best Interdisciplinary Engineering education program (in your point of view) so I could do the benchmark.

Comment: "If you have an hammer, everything looks like a nail". Try to provide your students with a complete set of tools.